# why output of a module can't reach from outside module

Tags: verilog

I write two module by Verilog. 
first module is 4 bit counter:

```
module  ASYNCHRONOUS_COUNTER( clk, res, out);

input clk;
input res;

output[3:0] out;

reg[3:0] out;
wire clk;
wire res;

initial 
    out = 4'b0;

always @(negedge clk or posedge res)
    if(res) begin
        out[0] <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        out[0] <= ~out[0];
    end

always @(negedge out[0] or posedge res)
    if(res) begin
        out[1] <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        out[1] <= ~out[1];
    end

always @(negedge out[1] or posedge res)
    if(res) begin
        out[2] <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        out[2] <= ~out[2];
    end

always @(negedge out[2] or posedge res)
    if(res) begin
        out[3] <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        out[3] <= ~out[3];
    end

endmodule
```

second module use first module :

```
module tripleInputClk(clk,tripledClk);

input clk;
wire clk;

output tripledClk;
wire tripledClk;

wire res;

wire[3:0] out;
reg temp;

initial
    temp <= 1'b0;

//assign out = 3'b0;

assign res = ~out[3] & ~out[2] & out[1] & out[0];

ASYNCHRONOUS_COUNTER myCounter(
.clk(clk),
.res(res),
.out(out)
);

always @(posedge res)
begin
    temp <= ~temp;
end

assign tripledClk = temp;

endmodule
```

first module works correctly, but when I compiled it and made it's wave form ,I understood that outputs of first module doesn't pass correctly and value of 'res' always equal '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `res` is declared as `wire` in your `tripleInputClk` module.

I simulated your code and observed that the signal `tripledClk` goes HIGH after **three** clock pulses. Thereby, suspecting that a `posedge` of `res` signal must occur. But, `res` is in continuous assignment statement. As soon as `res` becomes **HIGH**, the reg `out` changes (`@(posedge res)`) and again makes `res` **LOW**; all this **in a single time stamp**. So you are not able to view transition of res signal.

Also, after that, the `tripledClk` signal does not toggle as expected, I guess.

One way out is to declare `res` as `reg` in `tripleInputClk` module and **remove it from continuous assignment**. Instead, make it work on the **edge** of clock signal only.

This is because, reg is used to store values. Here, there is a **circular dependency** of `res` on `out` and vice-versa (i.e. `out` is also dependent on `res`). Henceforth, it creates some sort of confusing conditions(I would not term it as a race around condition exactly).

When you'll proceed to synthesis (even though *initial* block is not synthesizable here..!), the tool may issue this circular dependency *warning*. And, proper hardware may not be formed.

I've modified your code and provided a *testbench* to it. The only change is the one that I described here, i.e. `res` signal. Kindly go through the link below. The `tripledClk` is now also working fine as (3*frequency_of_clk).

Link to [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/V2q).